# How to insert SSI comments in Gatsby application?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, gatsby, ssi

I'm building a Gatsby app and I need to insert a few SSI lines (styled as HTML comments). Example

```html
<!--#set var="section" value="#{section}"-->
<!--#include virtual="/virtual/3.0/script-app.inc"-->
```

I can't find how to do this.

I need to put these (and other scripts) before the `head` tag, inside the `head` tag, at the end of the `body` tag and directly after it.

I've tried a lot of ways but none of them work. I've tried changing html.js but it just strips the comments out of the outputted code. I also tried working with gatsby-ssr and gatsby-browser but I keep thinking I don't know exactly what to do in those documents.

What I expect the output to be (with the exemplified codes):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--#set var="section" value="#{section}"-->
    <html>
        <head>
             <!--#include virtual="/virtual/3.0/script-app.inc"-->
             [rest of head code]
        </head>
    <body>
</html>
```

What happens: my output page has no comments whatsoever OR has it stringified (as in `&lt;!--#include virtual="/virtual/3.0/script-app.inc"--&gt;`

Comment: If you get no answers here you should open a github issue in the official gatsby repository. The project maintainers should know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `gatsby-node.js` and `onPostBuild()`. Copying the `html/js` then adding custom components (like `<ssi-code />` then replacing them using [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file):

```js
  replace.sync({
    files: ['./public/**/*.html', './public/*.html'],
    from: /<SSI-before-html>(.*?)<\/SSI-before-html>/g,
    to: '<!--#include virtual="/virtual/example.inc"-->',
  });
```