# Gatsby JS- How to properly add an html comment inside head in gatsbyjs?

Tags: gatsby

I followed the instructions on gatsbys website and did the following:

1. cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
2. went inside the (by gatsby created) html.js file and added a comment in the head section.
3. instead of   I used  {/* */} as the first was throwing an error
4. when i run gatsby develop i first get an error loading /query the 404 page and then other pages as well

Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details or some code?

Comment: Error: Couldn't get query results for ... (...any page i visit)

Comment: I still don't understand what are you trying to do. Can you clarify why do you want to add comments in the `<head>`? Can you provide the code about what have you tried so far?

Comment: please provide code, nobody understands what you are trying to do.

Comment: there is no code. i got gatsbys custom html.js file. did NOT add code. as i said, i added a comment in the head. i need to add a comment in the head, thats all (dont think the reason is related to my errors...) So i dont know how to be more clear on what im trying to do as I simply and only wanted to add a comment in the head section of the gatsbys html.js file. that is all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/):

> **Inserting HTML into the** `<head>`
>
> Anything you render in the `html.js`
> component will not be made “live” in the client like other components.
> If you want to dynamically update your  we recommend using [React
> Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/)

So, you can't customize the `<head>` tag directly with the `html.js` file.  Moreover, Gatsby gets rid off the SSI comments (you can follow the stack trace in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19336)).

Said that. You can try using [`gatsby-plugin-html-comments`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-html-comments/):

```
module.exports = {
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-html-comments`,
    options: {
      files: ['./public/**/*.html', './public/*.html'],
      comment: [
        {
          regexp: /<keep-this-comment-tag>(.*?)<\/keep-this-comment-tag>/g,
          comment: `<!-- keep this comment -->`,
          },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Will output:

```
  <div>
    <!-- keep this comment -->
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
```

You an also use one of the APIs that Gatsby exposes to customize the output, `onPostBuild` should work for you. Copying the `html/js` then adding custom components (like `<ssi-code />` then replacing them using [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file):

```js
  replace.sync({
    files: ['./public/**/*.html', './public/*.html'],
    from: /<SSI-before-html>(.*?)<\/SSI-before-html>/g,
    to: '<!--#include virtual="/virtual/example.inc"-->',
  });
```

*Source: [How to insert SSI comments in Gatsby application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730558/how-to-insert-ssi-comments-in-gatsby-application)*

Additionally, you can, as the thread suggests:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<!--#set var="section" value="#{section}"-->'}}></div>
```

Comment: if i add it to head, my comment wont be visible in the head section-

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've redone the full answer. Take a look at it to find new solutions: gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-html-comments Gatsby gets rids of SSI comments so we will need to customize a little bit the outputted HTML

Comment: thank you. dangerouslySetInnerHTML does not work. the plugin i tried, added it to config and that added <keep-this-comment-tag></keep-this-comment-tag> inside the helmet but nothing happens either

Comment: What about the `onPostBuild`?

Comment: I dont really understand it. "copy html/js  and adding custom components " means I do cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js, then inside that file i add custom components? how do I add it there?

Comment: Yes, copying the html/js (like you did at the beginning) but, then, you need to install the `replace-in-file` dependency to add your comment

Comment: So in gatsby.node I added the following: exports.onPostBuild = () => {
  replace.sync({
    files: ['./public/**/*.html', './public/*.html'],
    from: /<ssi-before-html>(.*?)<\/ssi-before-html>/g,
    to: "<!--comment-->",
  })
} then in the html file that I copied I add  <ssi-before-html /> inside head. but its still not visible inside head, instead in source code i can see the tag   <ssi-before-html /> inside body. I dont get why in body and also its never been transpiled, i just see the tag   <ssi-before-html />

Comment: Regarding the plugin (preferred and less aggressive method), have you tried adding something inside the comment tag? It's a regexp so...

Comment: yes also tried that, but that doesnt work. also on gatsbys website they make clean, the tag alone will be translated into whatever string you give to comment